# Hyper terminal and conda prints empty line when starting

Tags: terminal, zsh, datascience-anaconda

I have and "aesthetic" problem regarding my Hyper terminal. When I start it, (probably) something happens in the `~/.zshrc` file and it prints and ugly empty line with a `%` in the terminal.[image]

I am not sure if this problem actually comes from the `~/.zshrc` file, however, here is the conda initialise section of my `~/.zshrc` file.

I would like to get rid of this `%` getting printed every time I open my terminal.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$('/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2>                /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after playing around, I found out that the error happens when the window is too small. Tried to resize it and made it wider solved the issue.

Sometimes the most simple things are the exact solution.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol

Comment: Thanks Jeff, exactly this!