# Why am I seeing % as the line end when running cat file cmd

Tags: zsh, cat, text, newlines

This really confused me, when I do a cat cmd, I always see something like % at the end of a file, but if I open the file on editor or sublime, it is gone. So how to make sure my file is in a correct format
for example, run cmd `cat -e test.txt`

```
abc$
sdf$
adg$
adsf$
afg%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582)

Answer (score 8):

It's [zsh's way of showing that your file ends with an unterminated line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol). You'd see something similar with the `fish` shell which (confusingly) uses a `⏎` character instead where available or `^J` otherwise.

With most other shells (or with zsh if you turn off this feature), you'd see the prompt immediately after `afg` on the same line, and with some shells there would be display glitches because the shell expects the prompt to be at the left margin.

Normally, on Unix-like systems, the newline character is a line terminator: every line must end with a newline character. A text file consists of a sequence of lines, so a non-empty text file always ends with a newline character. (This is different from Windows where the newline character sequence (CR+LF) is usually a line separator, and so text files often don't end with a line break.)

Some text processing tools do not process the last line of a file correctly if it isn't terminated by a newline, although most modern programs will automatically add a final newline character if one is missing. A missing final newline can have surprising consequences; for example, if you concatenate the file with another file, `afg` will be concatenated with the first line of the other file, not on a line of its own.

Many editors automatically end files with a newline, so that they're valid text files. The ones that don't systematically do it by default can usually be configured to do so.